# Are there gaming and movies galleries?

Tags: resource-recommendations

I was wondering if anyone knows websites which are full of images from different games and movies

Like the css galleries but for movies and games (just for inspiration)

Hope you can help - thanks

Comment: Both are rather offtopic here. In addition gaming and movies are rather distinct subject to be dealt with in a single question. There are no appropriate movies stackexchange site just yet, but you can ask game design related questions at [gamedev.stackexchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @koiyu I think he's designing something related to gaming and movies stylistically perhaps and was wondering if there was any base for inspiration about those two elements to assist with the design. Design related nonetheless. Reopen? Closing this question is like closing a question about designing a mechanic's website because mechanic's aren't design related... websites are

Comment: @Daniel so should we allow queries like "Are there x websites?" just because they can be seen as inspirational? Or: "I need to draw a lightbulb for my ad; what kind of lightbulbs exist?" With such reasoning, almost ANY question (or more aptly: query) would be seen as on-topic. IMO this question might need some hundred or two more words for further elaboration + a clear point of focus to be useful and answerable.

Comment: @koiyu then a prompt to clarify as opposed to an outright closure? Closing questions that could be made valid doesn't help this site's statistics. I know you didn't close it, but this is addressed to @Philip Regan also

Comment: @Daniel Hanly, @koiyu: I have reopened the question with a justification for my initial closing and subsequent reopening in @Daniel's question on meta.

Comment: @aurel Could you give us an idea about why you want to have inspiration, what kind of project are you creating? Movies and Games deal with hundreds of genres and thus have different associated imagery, give us an idea about what your creating and we'll see if we can help.

Comment: Meta-question @Philip refers to: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156/reopen-a-question-bad-wording-bred-misunderstanding

Comment: I thought this was closed, thanks for re-opening, @daniel I am not looking for anything specific, I was just wondering if there are website like http://designshack.co.uk which only deal with movie images/effects/characters

Comment: games (computer games or real games like basketball and all)?

Answer (score 3):

**its hard to find such dedicated image gallery site for games and movies**

but i tried to collect some sites for you.

i dont know exactly what you need but try these links might be you get some inspiration by moving in.

1. http://skenko.com
2. http://scifiupdates.com/
3. http://giantbomb.com/
4. http://gallery.clickeep.com/
5. http://images.maxabout.com/

---

For movies

1. http://movies.ign.com
2. http://hollywood-movie-stills.blogspot.com
3. http://photogallery.indiatimes.com

---

Image Hub

1. http://free-extras.com
2. http://images.md/
3. http://.imagehousing.com
4. http://Photobucket.com
5. http://availableimages.com/

**And i am really very sorry if links are not useful for you...:|**